# css menu sub-items below can't be reached on hover

Tags: css, wordpress

I have a css menu in Wordpress with 3 levels, and the problem is that the level below the menu level2 with level 3 opened can't be reached on hover (the complete 2nd level menu closes).
Any help please?

My code is:

```
<div class="nav">
<ul>
    <li><a href="#">Main-menu</a>
<ul class="sub-menu">
    <li><a href="#">Sub-item</a></li>
    <li><a href="#">Second-submenu</a>
    <ul class="sub-menu">
        <li><a href="#">XY</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">XY</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">XY</a></li>
    </ul>
</li>
    <li><a href="#">Last-sub-menu</a>
    <ul class="sub-menu">
        <li><a href="#">XY</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">XY</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">XY</a></li>
    </ul>
</li>
</ul>
</li>
    <li><a href="#">Second-item</a></li>
    </ul>
</div>
```

And the css:

```
.nav { font-size:1.4em; }

.nav ul { padding:0; margin: 0; background: #0A488E; }

.nav ul li { display:inline-block; margin-right:5%; }

.nav ul li a { color:white; }

.nav li ul.sub-menu {
  display: none;
  position: absolute;
  padding: 7px 21px;
  padding-left: 21px;
  text-align: left;
  margin-left: -21px;
  background: #0A488E;
  font-size: 0.9em;
  z-index: 100;
}

.nav li:hover > ul.sub-menu, .nav li ul.sub-menu li:hover > ul.sub-menu {
display: block;
}

.nav li ul.sub-menu li {
display:block;
margin: 9px 0;
}

.nav li ul.sub-menu li ul.sub-menu {
  position: relative;
  padding: 0 5%;
}
```

The fiddle is here: https://jsfiddle.net/f7ny3s3r/2/

(The Last sub-menu is the problematic one)

Thank you for the help!

Comment: It works, it's just the way you have these items set up to work. When you move your mouse down through second sub menu - it opens and and closes when the mouse leaves it. When the mouse leaves it at the bottom it makes that menu smaller so you cannot hit the bottom item. A suggestion might be to have the sub-sub items come out of a side.

Comment: Also - I know this is marked css only so this is just a suggestion - but if you wouldn't mind adding a little js/jquery you could change the sub menu to a click.

Comment: Thank you, but I would like to keep the menu css and on hover - if it's possible since the main menu items have also respective pages.

Comment: Btw. any possibility to delay the closing of the opened menu, so it let's the user hover over the bottom one?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Based on what you are asking for, I fixed it here -

https://jsfiddle.net/f7ny3s3r/7/

Instead of display: none into display block. You can keep it block and use height and opacity with a transition. This will solve your problem, and add animation.

So instead of :

```
.nav li ul.sub-menu {
  display: none;
```

Use:

```
.nav li ul.sub-menu {
transition: 0.5s all;
display: block;
height: 0;
opacity:0;
```

And

```
.nav li:hover > ul.sub-menu, .nav li ul.sub-menu li:hover > ul.sub-menu {
height: auto;
opacity:1;
}
```

You can change the transition to whatever you want, including a delay (or no transition at all).

Comment: Thank you, it works! It's still a bit clonky at some places where the 2nd level Sub-menus overlap, but it's acceptable this way. Cheers!

Comment: Sorry a small mistake in the script: it triggers even when not over the main menu itself, but on the invisible sub-menu :-( Any chance to make it work better?

Comment: @Gas its because the submenu has padding/margin on it before it is hovered, and the li's inside of it as well shouldn't be block untill hovered. you could do the samething with the li's inside and just make them height 0 and opacity 0 until the hover above it is fired.

Comment: OK, I added these, it seems to work. 
`.nav li ul.sub-menu li, .nav li ul.sub-menu li a {
height: 0;
opacity:0;
display:none;
}

.nav li:hover > ul.sub-menu li,
.nav li:hover > ul.sub-menu li a { 
display:block; 
}

.nav li:hover > ul.sub-menu, 
.nav li ul.sub-menu li:hover > ul.sub-menu,
.nav li:hover > ul.sub-menu li,
.nav li:hover > ul.sub-menu li a {
height: auto;
opacity:1;
}`
I still have to adjust the margin/padding on some elements though...

Comment: Argh, maybe it is best to maek it jQuery after all, somehow it doesn't work well in pure css... :-(

Comment: @Gas yeah, if you want this to truely be pure css i might consider starting fresh from the ground up, otherwise jquery/jacascript could help you fix this quickly